# How to create a white border circle having white exclamation mark inside a box having a yellow background in html/css?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a white border circle having a white exclamation mark inside a yellow background box. The HTML and CSS code of the yellow background box is:

HTML:

```
<p class="my-paragraph-style">List your dependents and enter their personal information. Pay close attention to information regarding your spouse’s smoking habits.</p>
```

CSS:

```
.dependents  .my-paragraph-style
{
    background: #EABB27;
    padding: 20px;
    line-height: 1.4;
    position: relative;
    top: -25px;
}
```

The pictorial representation of the yellow background box which I have got from the above code (HTML and CSS) is:
[image: Yellow Background Box]

My task is to make a white border circle having a white exclamation mark inside a yellow box. Below is an image what I exactly want inside a yellow background box:[image]

In order to achieve that, I have cropped the circle from the section of a yellow background box. After cropping it, I have used the following CSS code in order to get the circle inside the box.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 320px)
{
.info-mobile-header-sections 
{ /* Info icon for header parts of sections */
    background: url(img/147811205179656.png) no-repeat;
    margin-top: -3px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 200;
    left: 15px;
}
}
```

The 147811205179656.png is a cropped image [image] from the section of a yellow box.

By using the above CSS code, I am able to get only some section of the circle inside the yellow box and that too not aligned properly. Let me know if I am following the right approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need to use an image here, it's easier, faster, more scalable and flexible to use a pseudo element like `::before` here:

[image]

```css
.my-paragraph-style {
  background: #EABB27;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 50px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  position: relative;
  font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  max-width: 300px;
}
.my-paragraph-style::before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 23px;
  content: "!";
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  color: yellow;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<p class="my-paragraph-style">List your dependents and enter their personal information. Pay close attention to information regarding your spouse’s smoking habits.</p>
```

Comment: It works, thank you connexo. Just one quick question, in the actual image I want only habits in the last line instead of smoking habits. How can I achieve this ? I tried playing with padding, line-height and font-size in the class .my-paragraph-style but still I wasn't able achieve that. Is there anyway I can achieve it through CSS ?

Comment: No, you cannot control the exact point for a linebreak with CSS in that fashion. You need to try and find fitting values for the parameters that influence this (which I would not advise to do since content tends to change often).

Answer (score 3):

You can create that with just `:before` pseudo-element and `Flexbox`.

```css
.my-paragraph-style {
  background: #EABB27;
  padding: 20px;
  max-width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  color: white;
}
.my-paragraph-style:before {
  flex: 0 0 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: '!';
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<p class="my-paragraph-style">List your dependents and enter their personal information. Pay close attention to information regarding your spouse’s smoking habits.</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

CSS

```
.my-paragraph-style
{
    background: #EABB27;
    padding: 40px;
    line-height: 1.4;
    position: relative;
    top: -25px;
}

.my-paragraph-style:before {
  content:"!";
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%
}
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/bavesirele/edit?html,css,output)

You can tinker with the css as per your liking.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.my-paragraph-style {
    background: #EABB27;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 50px;
    line-height: 1.4;
 color: #fff;
}

.my-paragraph-style:before {
 content: '!';
 height: 20px;
 width: 20px;
 display: block;
 border: 2px solid red;
 border-radius: 50%;
 text-align: center;
 color: red;
 float: left;
 margin-left: -35px;
}
```

```html
<p class="my-paragraph-style">List your dependents and enter their personal information. Pay close attention to information regarding your spouse’s smoking habits.</p>
```